# Problem with showing shapefile in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, ogr

I have a number of shapefiles from a customer.  I can read them with both ogrinfo and QGIS.

They don't have a .prj file, but I know that the projection is EPSG:3006.

When I add them as layers in GeoServer, I declare the projection to be EPSG:3006 in the box "Declared SRS" by inputing "EPSG:3006". I set "SRS Handling" to be "Force declared".

It makes no difference if I add a .prj file with a projection definition. I can then calculate the bounds successfully.

When I try to preview the layer in OpenLayers, I get an empty map. When I try to load the layer as WFS, I get an empty result.

There are no error messages in the logs as far as I can see. I have tried to change the log level.

If I run ogr2ogr and save them as new shapefiles, they work in GeoServer. 
If I export them to a new shapefile from QGIS, they work in GeoServer.

Is there a way I can use OGR or QGIS to show my customer what the problem is?

Comment: how do you "declare the projection to be EPSG:3006"?

Comment: I edited my question to expand on this. Short version: I use the Declared SRS box.

Comment: can you post the ogrinfo output

Comment: Unfortunately not since it is customer specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that in the original file, record numbers start at 0.
Geotools (used by Geoserver) doesn't like this, since the specification states that record numbers start at 1.